# Laravel / Eloquent / Postgres: UPDATE query causes error "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have this Eloquent query in vendor code from [this](https://github.com/exatech-group/Laravel-H5P) package:

```
H5pContent::where('library_id', $library_id)->update(['filtered' => null]);
```

I use Postgres for my app. The package is hardwired for MySQL, so I had to make some changes, but I'd expect this query to work with Postgres as well. However, it doesn't:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
(SQL: update "h5p_contents" set "filtered" = ?, "updated_at" = 2020-09-23 09:41:46 where "library_id" = 146)
```

This is a typical error I get from above query. It seems that the only parameter, `null`, has been filtered out in some way. What's wrong here?

**edit**

Even this simple query causes the same error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`:

```
H5pContent::where("library_id", $library_id)->get();
```

The SQL generated from this query is

```
select * from "h5p_contents" where "library_id" = 291
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\DB::Raw()` :

As per error description, it is not getting value for fields.

`H5pContent::where('library_id', $library_id)->update(['filtered' => \DB::raw(null) ]);`

Comment: That actually makes a difference (even though I don't understand why), but it doesn't solve my problem. When I write `\DB::raw(null)`, the question mark is replaced by nothing: `set "filtered" = , "updated_at" = 2020-09-23 [...]`. When I write `\DB::raw("NULL")`, the question mark is replaced by `NULL`: `set "filtered" = NULL, "updated_at" = 2020-09-23 [...]`. The error message remains the same.

Comment: Check in your database. Is `filtered` column set to NULL or not.

Comment: When I do something that leads to this error, nothing is written to the DB. But I'm not sure if that's what you're asking: When I check the DB, there is no `null` in this column, but it's permitted.

Comment: What is the value of `DB_CONNECTION` in `.env` file ?

Comment: `DB_CONNECTION` is `pgsql`.

Comment: Try to run `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` and then execute your code.

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't help (I didn't expect it to as this all happens inside a freshly built container).

Comment: Try to change value of `sslmode` in `config\database.php` and set to `disable`. and also clear cache and execute script.

Comment: Turns out the problem was in `$library_id`: This contains an array actually, and it seems MySQL could handle the query Eloquent generates from `where` with an Array while Postgres can't. All I had to do was to use `whereIn`: `H5pContent::whereIn('library_id', $library_id)->update(['filtered' => null]);` Thank you for your help!!!